# disable Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the below code in CSHTML but seems like the dropdown is not getting disabled

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Task_Status_Code, Model.TaskStatus, new {  @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

I want to disable it but it is not working.

Comment: Your code looks correct. It should work fine. Have you done any implementation in `javascript` which might enables it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with below snippet !

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ReminderTime,
    Model.RemindersList,
    new { disabled = "disabled" }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.Task_Status_Code, 
Model.TaskStatus, 
new {  @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

Removed the @ sign before the `disabled` property name.

You need to add the @ character before any dotnet keywords like `class`. Custom properties do not need to have @ prefix.

Comment: thanks worked.if I will put condition like this it is not working if (@Convert.ToBoolean(Session["isUTFTStatusEdit"]))
                $("#Task_Status_Code").prop("disabled", true);
            else
            $("#Task_Status_Code").prop("disabled", false);

Comment: Glad that it worked. Are the javascript codes executing? i.e. `Session` variable is not null right? Also you do not have a `if` statement?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@if(Convert.ToBoolean(Session["isUTFTStatusEdit"]))` instead of `(@Convert.ToBoolean(Session["isUTFTStatusEdit"]))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Task_Status_Code, Model.TaskStatus, new {  disabled = "disabled" })
```

> That will work as well unless you define css form control with in then

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Task_Status_Code, Model.TaskStatus, new { @class="form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

> Remember not to put @sign before disabled